# Triggered Send EmailAddress variable

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, triggered-send, marketingcloudapi

I've inherited a triggered send for which the payload looks like this:

```
{
    "To": {
        "Address":"x@gmail.com",
        "SubscriberKey":"x@gmail.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "user_first_name":"X",
                "user_language":"en",
                "password_url":"https://some_url.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the send log data extension, I have the following fields:
[image: Attributes of send log DE]

Does SFMC automatically recognise the "Address" as "EmailAddress" for a triggered send?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct format and will correctly connect to 'EmailAddress' inside the Data Extension. See [official docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/messageDefinitionSends.htm) here for details.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I was unable to retrieve this information from the docs as it's not explicitly stated.